# Bounding an integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to show that the following integral ( a solution for the non-homogeneous transport equation ) has this bound:
$$
\begin{equation*}
     \left\|{ \int_{0}^{t} f(x+b(w-t),w) dw }\right\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{t}{\left |{b}\right |^{n-1}} \left\|{f}\right\|_{\infty}
\end{equation*}
$$

Where $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ , $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

**Solution attempt**

The instructor hinted us to use change of variables on the integral, my idea was to find a function $s(w) : \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ so the composition $f\circ{s}$ is a single variable (continuous) function and the integral can be bounded like this:
$$
\begin{equation*}
     \left\|{ \int_{0}^{t} f\circ{s}(w) dw }\right\|_{\infty} \leq t \left\|{f}\right\|_{\infty}
\end{equation*}
$$

however I'm having trouble connecting the two equations, my candidate is $s_i(w) = (x_i + b_i(w-t))$ for the first n components and $s_{n+1}(w) = w $ but I'm havng trouble connecting the two integrals.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information about $f$ to prove the inequality you want.  Take $f$ constant and positive; then we have $\int_0^t f\,dw=tf=t||f||_\infty$ and not $tf/|b|^{n-1}$.

Comment: you are right, in the book we are only assuming f is continuous so the bound might fail if f is constant and b is big :( , that's .... interesting.